# Multiple statement query throwing error in nodeJS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, error-handling

In my application, i need to execute multiple select statements in a single query.
I'm using node-querybuilder

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-querybuilder

I'm using its .query method to execute a custom query(without query generation)
Here is the code

```
    user.earning_information = function(key){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let balance = user.userData.balance;
        let query = "SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = "+key+";";
            query += "SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = "+key+" AND `type` LIKE 'ref%';";
            query += "SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref1` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = "+key+" AND `type` = 'ref';";
            query += "SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref2` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = "+key+" AND `type` = 'ref_pa';";
            query += "SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref3` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = "+key+" AND `type` = 'ref_supa';";
            query += "SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_invest` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = "+key+" AND `type` = 'invest';";
        console.log(query);
        dbc.db_query(query).then(function(data){            
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

I've logged the query to the console and this is what i got, i even ran this on phpmyadmin and it works and returns the data.

SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 157632672;SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 157632672 AND `type` LIKE 'ref%';SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref1` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 157632672 AND `type` = 'ref';SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref2` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 157632672 AND `type` = 'ref_pa';SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref3` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 157632672 AND `type` = 'ref_supa';SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_invest` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 157632672 AND `type` = 'invest';

However, when i run it programatically, it throws this error.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 15763' at line 1
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `total_earnings_ref` FROM `earnings` WHERE `tid` = 15763' at line 1
```

Any idea as to why this happens? 
Database is mySQL, by the way and the error says MariaDB.

Comment: Does you db library supports multi query ?

Comment: Try to use knex. http://knexjs.org/

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I thought it did not matter, node-querybuilder uses the mysql module so i figured i could run a query like any other.

Comment: Well if the query builder is not designed to run multiple query in a single statement then it will fail. But if you run one query at a time it should work. The error message that you have pointed out its certainly the 2nd query after the first delimiter `;` is considered as a part of the query statement and it got broken. Hence I asked if the DB layer is capable of running multiple statements at a time separated by the delimiter `;`

Comment: Also the module that you are using is not so so popular what I can see on NPM try using some better ORM like waterline which is built on Sails.js and for batch query the node-querybuilder perhaps does not support that.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I solved it, all i had to do was set multipleStatements to true in the settings for the mysql module.

Comment: Awesome !! So the module does support multiple query statement execution good to know.